# Android: Handler.postDelayed doesn't stop

Tags: java, android, handler, runnable

I am unable to stop handler.postDelayed from example below. It simply continues to do function after 1 second, and doesn't stop when switch is off:

```
    mySwitch.setChecked(false);
    mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            final Handler handler = new Handler();

            final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    myClient.SendData("AA");
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                }
            };
            if (isChecked){
                handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
            }
            else {
                handler.removeCallbacks(r);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

> and doesn't stop when switch is off:

that's because you are instantiating r every time the callback is being called. Move

```
   final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
             myClient.SendData("AA");
             handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
   };
```

outside the callback. In the scope of your method or of the class